# Javascript callbacks fundamentals from C# point of view

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

Please help me understand two thing about callbacks. They are the last JS weirdness left for me that I can't grasp having strong C# background.

First - why should we send function as parameters. I know that we can, but why. I will try the simplest example I can think of. So according to the JS developers it should be like this:

```
function simpleCallbackFn(){}

function simpleCallerFn(cb){ cb();}

simpleCallerFn(simpleCallbackFn);
```

Why not like this:

```
function simpleCallbackFn(){} // Same as before

function simpleCallerFn(){ 
  simpleCallbackFn();
}
```

We do not pass a callback, we simply call it from within the caller. It is within perfectly visible scope. Then we just make the initial call.

```
simpleCallerFn();
```

Calling the "callback" function from within the caller function to me should be perfectly fine and achieve the same result.

Second - say I need to use callback with arguments

```
function simpleCallbackFn(anArgument){}

function simpleCallerFn(cb){ 
   cb(anArgument);
}
```

We know that this will not work
`simpleCallerFn (simpleCallbackFn(anArgument));`

According to the JS developers it should be like this:

`simpleCallerFn (() => simpleCallbackFn(anArgument));`

I am thinking why not:

```
function simpleCallbackFn(anArgument){}

function simpleCallerFn(anArgument, cb){ 
   cb(anArgument);
}
```

Then make the initial call like this:

```
simpleCallerFn(anArgument, simpleCallbackFn);
```

Then combining my first and second approach:

```
function simpleCallbackFn(anArgument){}

function simpleCallerFn(anArgument){ 
   simpleCallbackFn(anArgument);
}

simpleCallerFn(anArgument);
```

Please. That Javascript makes me fell like in freak's circus.

Thank you.

Comment: `We do not pass a callback, we simply call it from within the caller.` Maybe it's not convenient or possible to modify the code of the caller, it could be part of an external library or a browser component.

Comment: I don't see how the answer to these questions would be any different in JavaScript than in C#

Comment: @Bergi is correct. Consider something like `listOfNumbers.Select(x => x*2)` you can express the same considerations - why pass a callback instead of directly calling a method? Why should the callback receive an argument? Why don't you pass the argument with the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not like this:
>
> ```
> function simpleCallbackFn (){} // Same as before
>
> function simpleCallerFn (){ simpleCallbackFn ();}
> ```

That's certainly legal code, but it's only possible if you know ahead of time exactly what code to execute. The point of a callback function is that you can decide what you want to do at runtime.

For example, there's a built in function that arrays have called `.map`. It takes an array and converts it to a new array. You pass in a callback function specifying how to do that conversion, and `.map` will call your function for each element of the array. There's no other way `.map` could be implemented, because there's no way to know ahead of time what conversion you want to do.

```
const values = [1, 2, 3];
const doubled = values.map(val => val * 2);
// doubled contains [2, 4, 6]
```

btw, a simplified implementation of map would look something like this:

```
function map(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  // where `this` is the input array -- values in my example
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    newArray[i] = callback(this[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

> We know that this will not work simpleCallerFn (simpleCallbackFn(anArgument));

That's correct. And just to state the reason why it doesn't work: the order of operations for this line moves from the inside out. Basically, it means "immediately call `simpleCallbackFn(anArgument)`, and then pass the result into `simpleCallerFn`". So we end up passing in `undefined` instead of a callback function.

On the other hand, `simpleCallerFn(() => simpleCallbackFn(anArgument));` means "Create a function with the text `() => simpleCallbackFn(anArgument)` and pass it into `simpleCallerFn`".

> I am thinking why not:
>
> ```
> function simpleCallbackFn (anArgument){}
>
> function simpleCallerFn (anArgument, cb){ 
>   cb(anArgument);
> }
> ```

That works if you're certain that the callback wants exactly one argument to be passed in to it. But it won't work if they need 2 or more, and if they need 0 it will be more combersome than necessary.

So the benefit of having the user of this code create a callback function is that they can make *any* function, with any requirements they can dream up.

Comment: Regarding your ending comments:

"That works if you're certain that the callback wants exactly one argument to be passed in to it. But it won't work if they need 2 or more ..."

Well, if it needs more arguments, we will pass more.

How more beneficial it would be if we were using JS ways if it needs more arguments ??

Like what we mentioned:

simpleCallerFn(() => simpleCallbackFn(anArgument));

Comment: `Well, if it needs more arguments, we will pass more`. The problem is when you don't know the number of arguments. `simpleCallfFn` needs to work with callbacks that require 0 arguments, and also callbacks that require 1, and also 2, 3, etc. Supporting 0-N arguments with your approach is possible (either using arrays or rest params), but it's much simpler to just let the person who calls `simpleCallferFn` create a function that does exactly what they want, and not have to anticipate all their needs.

Comment: Also, # of arguments is not the only thing that callback functions might care about; `this` binding may be important to them as well, and there may be some more obscure uses i'm not thinking of. It would be possible to make your code more complex to support setting `this`. But there's also a solution that fits all parameter lengths, all uses of `this`, and all things i havn't thought of, and requires no effort when writing `simpleCallerFn`: Have them create a function that does what they want, and pass it in to you.